# Expression for the centripetal acceleration

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-kinematics, centripetal-force

Is the expression $$\frac{v^2}{r}$$ for centripetal acceleration,only valid for uniform circular motion, or is it also valid even when particle is moving in a non-uniform circular motion?

Comment: It applies to any smooth path. And the specific case of non-uniform circular motion is explicitly discussed [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_motion#Non-uniform).

Answer (score 1):

With little differential geometry, velocity and acceleration can be written as:

\begin{align*}
  \mathbf{v} &= \dot{s} \, \mathbf{T} \\
  &= v \, \mathbf{T} \\
  \mathbf{a} &= \ddot{s} \, \mathbf{T}+ \kappa \, \dot{s}^2\mathbf{N} \\
  &= \frac{d^2s}{dt^2} \mathbf{T} + \frac{v^2}{\rho} \mathbf{N} \\
  &= v\frac{dv}{ds} \mathbf{T} + \frac{v^2}{\rho} \mathbf{N} \\
\end{align*}

where $s$ is the arclength, $\kappa$ is the curvature and $\rho$ is the radius of curvature.

Acceleration will include the tangential component (along $\mathbf{T}$) and normal component (along $\mathbf{N}$) which is the centripetal acceleration but is given by radius of curvature instead.

See also [**answer 1**](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/310064/question-about-a-v-mathrm-dv-mathrm-dx/310072#310072) and [**answer 2**](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/317192/prove-a-force-driven-by-a-cross-product-between-a-vector-and-its-velocity-gives/317272#317272) of mine.